# Define a function for "height" in ggsave depending on the number of rows in facet_grid

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, facet-grid, ggsave

For each element of my list of data (`data_l`) I got a plot with this simple function :

```
data_l <- split(data,list(data$Sample.type,data$Locality), drop=TRUE)
lapply(names(data_l), function(i){
  ggplot(data_l[[i]], aes(Date, Concentration, group = Chemicals, col = as.factor(Chemicals))) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point() +
    facet_grid(cols = vars(Chemicals), rows = vars(Locality), scales = "fixed") +
    ylab(paste("Concentrations in", data_l[[ i ]]$Measuring.Unit[ 1 ])) +
    ggsave(paste(i, ".png", sep = ""),  dpi = 400, width = 30, height = 20, units = "cm")
})
dev.off()
```

I fixed in `ggsave` the height at 20 cm. But, depending on the number of facets, the plot size
has to be adapted for each element of the list.

Is it possible to define a function for "height" in `ggsave` that would take into account the number of `rows` in `facet_grid` ? (10 cm if 1 row in `facet_grid`, 20 cm if 2 rows,...)

Comment: You could count the number of levels in the dimension and multiply height by some predefined factor...